# C# XML merge child node names with parent names and values

Tags: c#, xml

I want to merge the names of parent nodes with names of child nodes to bring all to the top level.  I don't even know where to start with code on this. I am using C#.  I wish to exclude the root node from the merge process.

```
Example before:
    <root>
       <lastname>string</lastname>
       <firstname>string</firstname>
       <student>
          <id>string</id>
          <ssn>string</ssn>
       </student>
    </root>

XML after:
    <root>
       <lastname>string</lastname>
       <firstname>string</firstname>
       <studentid>string</studentid>
       <studentssn>string</studentssn>
    </root>
```

So the student parent has been merged with the id and ssn.  Any help would be appreciated if this is even possible.

Comment: Some more constraints are necessary, or you'll get a collection of nodes `<rootlastname>`, `<rootfirstname>`, `<rootstudentid>` and `<rootstudentssn>`... :)

Comment: I added a clarifying note to the description.  Thanks

Comment: Surely this is possible. But the way to do it depends on the tools you have. Do you want to use a [DOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model) representation? Are you using some library with XML parser and serializer? Are you going to process the XML with XQuery? Or do you want to write an XML interpreter and builder yourself from scratch...? You can also do it with standard Linux command-line text-manipulating tools like `awk` or possibly even with `sed`.